# Make histogram from data frame column values greater than zero

Tags: r, loops, histogram

I have a data frame(Huc12) with a count field (Sum_Count). I wanted to create a histogram of the Sum_Count field for values greater than zero. Is it best to make a for loop for Huc12$Sum_Count > 0, then is it possible to do a histogram from that? If possible it would be nice to not have to subset out the data where Sum_COunt>0 to another data frame, but if that's the only way then I can go that route

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  if Huc12$Sum_Count > 0 
  hist(Huc12$Sum_Count)
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want `hist(Huc12$Sum_Count[Huc12$Sum_Count>0])`.

Comment: Or you could specifically tell `hist` to use zero as the low-end cutoff.  See `?hist`